# Acumatica sending mail server IP for Self Hosted In-House Exchange

Tags: acumatica

In order for us to allow the Acumatica system to relay our domain and send emails from the Acumatica system I need to open our firewall for the Acumatica sending mail servers. Does anyone happen to know the IP address or IP range of the Acumatica sending mail servers? We host our exchange in-house which is why it is needed.

Comment: As I know Acumatica hasn't its own Mail Servers. The system is using System Email Accounts and working with them via POP3/IMAP and SMTP protocols.

Comment: They have to be using some type of relaying server such as SendMail on Apache to send the email. I have every setting correct on my server and the Acumatica system but it is getting blocked by my firewall. Seems figuring out the relaying mail server IP is something that even Acumatica support does not know. Been trying to find out for almost two weeks now.

Comment: Have you tried to catch the request with https://www.wireshark.org/ or  https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: As Samvel Petrosov mentioned the configuration is not Acumatica specific. Acumatica allows you to configure the SMTP server used but beyond that configuration is specific to the external SMTP server. Generic SMTP configuration advice should do the job, I've posted an answer covering that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lookup the servers you are using on page System Email Accounts SM204002:
[image]

Usually it's trickier to identify the ports than the IP. For IP you can [resolve the host name](https://whatismyipaddress.com/hostname-ip) of the server. Ex: hostname is outlook.office365.com in image above, it resolves to:
[image]

The ports will very likely be the same as any other public SMTP server. You know which port to target based on SMTP server type (incoming/outgoing/relay), authentication support (SSL/TLS).  For reference from this [link](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We were able to figure it out by pinging our Acumatica site. With that IP we were able to put a secure path through our firewall so that it can talk to our internal exchange server. Hopefully, the IP will not change and this setting will continue to work.

For those who need the IP of there Acumatica site ping your site (ex. name.acumatica.com) this IP is the relying IP that Acumatica uses for your account to send mail through there system.

Answer (score 0):

IP Addresses can tend to change.  I believe what you are referring to is you are opening firewalls based on specific ip addresses.  The challenge there is the Acumatica IP address could change one day and without any notice your email will stop working.

I recommend using an SMTP Server that is open, but requires authentication (logging in) in order to relay emails.